# I am trying to normalize a pandas column--why does it keep crashing my computer?

Tags: python, pandas

Essentially, I am trying to use json_normalize to normalize a column in my pandas dataframe. The normalized portion only includes 5 additional columns which doesn't seem ludicrous to me--though the dataframe does have around 21,000 rows (which still doesn't seem like that much to me).

I have tried here to use a list comprehension to create a dataframe containing only the information that needs to be normalized, that I will later be able to join with the main dataframe.

```
dfNormalized = pandas.concat([df.append(json_normalize(x)) for x in 
data['email_addresses']], ignore_index=True)
```

The code will run for a little bit before my computer will freeze and all programs will freeze. I am then forced to manually turn off the computer. Am I doing this inefficiently? Does my computer just suck? I thought I remember that this worked yesterday, but maybe I'm remembering wrong because every time I try it today the ol machine blows up.

Comment: details on the box you're running this on? have you tried running it on other hardware? a virtualbox vm perhaps just for testing on the same rig? try expanding the loop and printing/logging the current time in milliseconds to see if it increases before the crash

Comment: if you can try it with few rows data and check the dataset size whether it is increases or not which may help you to know what wrong happened with earlier runs